# Is there an easy way to fill a 2d array after initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays

I currently have a 2d array in my program which stores the coordinates for a cube. It is initialized at the top and is easily filled with the values I want in it like so.

```
float cubeRef[3][8] = { { -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1 },
                        { 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1 },
                        { 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, }     };
```

However during my program the co ordinates change and I have a function which 'resets' them back to the default values you see above. However if I try to reset them using the same method as before.

```
cubeRef = { { -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1 },
            { 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, }     };
```

It will not work here, with error message "Expression must be a modifiable value".

Why can I not fill a 2d array after initializing the same way I can when I created it? And how can I return the 2d array to it's default values without having to fill each space individually?

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign to an array, it's simply not possible.

You *could* have two arrays, the one you modify, and one which contains the default values. Then when you want to reset the modifiable array you just copy from the default array, either using [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy), [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) or in a loop.

Otherwise you have to manually set each entry, one by one.